# Empty vs. not-loaded Ember.js controller

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

The handlebars `each` helper is used to iterate over a list of items in a backing `ArrayController`.

We can use the following construct to do something with a list of items AND show alternative details when that list is empty:

```
    {{#each item in controller}}
       <!-- stuff goes here -->
    {{else}}
       <!-- other stuff goes here -->
    {{/each}}
```

This is great, but what if we want to differentiate between `empty` and `not loaded`? I feel like this must be a fairly common use case, but I can't figure out how to approach it - I don't see anything in the guides. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this use case, i just wrap the "each" with a "if", that test an additional argument 'loaded' on the model.

```
{{#if content.loaded}}
   {{#each item in controller}}
       <!-- stuff goes here -->
    {{else}}
       <!-- other stuff goes here -->
    {{/each}}
{{/if}}
```

The 'loaded' is toggled to true when the ajax promise (or whatever you do) completes.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This pretty much does it! The structure boils down to adding an `{{else}}` to the `{{#if content.loaded}}` for the "still loading" state. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For me with Ember 1.8.1, Ember Data 1.0.0-beta11 and iterating over `hasMany` collection on a model `loaded` wasn't working, as well as `isLoaded`. The thing that worked was `isFulfilled`.